# ImproperlyConfigured at /login/ Error importing authentication backend backends.EmailAuthBackend: "No module named backends"

Tags: django, authentication

i'm working on Django project, i searched for a while how login and t found that the easiest way is to "django.contrib.auth". so i added my login view to urls.py :

```
 url(r'^login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name': 'login.html'}),
```

and this is my template :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django Bookmarks - User Login</title>
</head>
<h1>User Login</h1>
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match.
        Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
        {{ form.username }}</p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS part of your settings? I'm assuming you have changed it from the default one of django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend

Comment: no i didn't change it

Comment: Run `./manage.py shell` and show us `django.conf.settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, please.

Comment: have you rename your app folder or anything in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have added some custom backend in settings.py

Try this on shell:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS
```

Seems django is trying to import a module named `backends` which you do not have because of some path mistake you are making.

If `EmailAuthBackend` is defined in a module named `backends.py` in an app `some_app`, you need to add `some_app.backends.EmailAuthBackend` to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

Answer (score 0):

In early Django versions, this can be due to some `backends.py`.
I wanted to create an activation email and I used `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['authentication.backends.EmailBackend']` in my `settings.py` then I created a file named `backends.py`, afterward, I deleted `backeds.py` (because you won't need that in early Dj versions, at least for email verification) and I forgot to delete the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['authentication.backends.EmailBackend']` from my `settings.py`, and that caused the error.